# C++/winRT coroutine try/catch not working

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I have a C++/winRT coroutine that reads a file. The following 'gets' the file:

```
StorageFile _fileDoubles = co_await _turboCalc.GetFileAsync(L"FileDoubles.dbo");
```

Which executes properly because the file exists. If I change its name to a nonexistent file, my app fails with this error message:

> Exception thrown at 0x76903AC2 in IBuffer.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : winrt::hresult_error at memory location 0x02FBE338.

If I enclose it in the following `try`/`catch`, My app still fails and with the same error message.

```
try {
    StorageFile _fileDoubles = co_await_turboCalc.GetFileAsync(L"FileDoublesZZZ.dbo"); //doesn't exist
}
catch (hresult_error const & e) {
    printf("error: %ls\n", e.message().c_str());
```

}

What is the proper way to use `try`/`catch` in a couroutine?

Comment: This coroutine  is in an XAML button click handler. If I set Visual Studio /Debug/Windows/Exception Setting/C++ to OFF then the behavior is as if the GetFileAsnyc  exception. called an  immediate return thus avoiding any correction code that may exist..

Comment: The problem is that the coroutine refers to non local data. If I remove these references,  the try/catch works as advertised..